# could not display SVG image

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I want to display SVG image from URL, I am using SDWebImageSVGCoder but it could not display my image, but when I change the image with another one it displays it correctly.

my image url is: [mySVG](https://www.sharjahairport.ae/social/svg/ABY.svg)

```
    let svgURL = URL(string: element.logoURL)!

    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: svgURL) { (image, _, _, _) in
          if let img = image {
              cell.imgView.image = img
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have direct support for SVG. You need an external framework for this like [SwiftSVG](https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG)

Cocoapods:

```
pod 'SwiftSVG', '~> 2.0'
```

Code :

```
let svgURL = URL(string: "https://www.sharjahairport.ae/social/svg/ABY.svg")!

let svgView = UIView(SVGURL: svgURL) { (svgLayer) in
            
     svgLayer.resizeToFit(yourView.bounds)
}

// yourView is a UIView instead of a UIImageView
yourView.addSubview(svgView)
```

Comment: I tried it but it displays only black color

Comment: defs is unsupported. For a complete list of supported elements, see the `allSupportElements` variable in the `SVGParserSupportedElements` struct. Click through on the `elementName` variable name to see the SVG tag name.
pattern is unsupported. For a complete list of supported elements, see the `allSupportElements` variable in the `SVGParserSupportedElements` struct. Click through on the `elementName` variable name to see the SVG tag name.

Comment: XCode 12 have direct support for SVG and I tried your image directly in XCode and it's not rendering. Some other SVG's I tried working fine. Maybe it's the problem with your SVG.